# В чем разница между виртуальными машинами развернутыми из клона и из шаблона в VMware?

Tags: vmware

Хотелось бы узнать есть ли разница между виртуальными машинами развернутыми из клона и из шаблона? Особо интересует вопрос про нюансы типа SIDов, работы клонированных и развернутых из шаблона виртуальных машин в одном домене.